# windows phone 8 emulator throwing error when connecting to wcf service

Tags: windows-phone-8

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code while using windows phone 8 emulator

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get anywhere with this? Did you check your InnerException. I too, constantly get this error! My problem is related to ip address error where I didn't realise you had to set a specific IP address in your config file as WP8 is a virtual machine and therefore has its own local host but my problem is that it works, then stops, then eventually works again!! Very unstable behaviour.

Note this occurs with any errors, so you probably need to implement an IErrorHandler in wcf and return a proper error to your client.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer your question without more specific information. However, there are a couple of things you can look into:

**- Is the service the phone invokes running?**

Try to open the service from a web browser in your machine.

**- Can the emulator see the service?**

Try to open the service from a web browser in the emulator.

**- Is it a self-signed https service?**

You need to install the certificate in the emulator.

**- Does the service support basic http connection?**

Windows Phone 8 only supports basicHttpBinding.

**My [post](http://zengstephen.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/windows-phone-8-development-setup-https.html) might be able to give you some useful information.**